# Why it is showing a single button in Alert Dialog?

Tags: android

I want to show a large number of buttons in a Dialog box on the click of which the background is set of that color. But it is showing a single button of blue color what must i do so that it shows all the colours buttons

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    this);

            builder.setTitle("Set Background Color").setCancelable(false);
            builder.setNeutralButton("Red",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            // User clicked OK button
                            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNeutralButton("White",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                    });

            builder.setNeutralButton("Yellow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        }
                    });

            builder.setNeutralButton("Green", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                    ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
            });

            builder.setNeutralButton("Black", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                    ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            });

            builder.setNeutralButton("Blue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                    ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: I bet it is showing "Blue" button only because, each time you are creating a `NeutralButton`, is replaced by new created `NeutralButton`

Comment: You can  create Customised Alert Dialog Box 

Try this link: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: Insted of using setNeutralButton always use setNegativeButton and setPositiveButtons

Comment: @Abhi: I guess you can't create more than 3 buttons (neutral,positive,negative)in `AlertDialog`.Well you can customize it to achieve your goal.

Comment: Didn't really understand the reason for the downvote. Upvoted it to restore balance to the universe. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is showing blue because in your code you are constantly overwriting the other colours on the buttons. As far as I am aware, you can have only one neutral button. And what you are doing is creating a new neutral button every time and replacing the old one.

You need to create your custom XML layout with all the required buttons and inflate it.

OR, if you don't need too much customisations, you could just use the following snippet:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Set Background Color");
    builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]
            {"Red", "Green", "Black", "Blue"},
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                           ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
```

Comment: And don't forget to accept one of the answers here! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

try below code

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Set Background Color");
    builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]
            {"Red", "White", "Yellow", "Green", "Black", "Blue"},
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                    // of the selected item
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                           ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                              ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                              ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
```